# Does Google Web Search have convenient filters?

Tags: google-search

Is there any convenient way to filter Google Search results, e.g., by Date, like yandex.ru does:

[image: yandex.ru screen shot]

Comment: What else were you wanting to know about besides the date, if anything specific?

Comment: @Shule Wouldn't mind to specify more flexible time beyond past year. The search tool selection is too basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a search, you can filter by date in the search results window.  Click on the "Search tools" button below the search box, and the "Any time" dropdown list will appear below that.  Click on that and it will display options that let you filter the search results by date.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Beneath the Google search box, click on `Search tools` (last option). This opens an additional toolbar, beneath the main toolbar, that allows you to filter by location, time (date) and various other options.

The "Time" filter has options for:

- Any time (default)
- Past hour
- Past 24 hours
- Past week
- Past month
- Past year
- Custom range...

Answer (score 0):

You can use these shortcuts without going to advance tool. Not all of them may be but all the important ones.

1. `FIFA world cup "2014"` will return the specific result from 2014.
2. Use of `-` sign eliminates that entry from your search result ex:
   `FIFA world cup 2014 winner -Brazil` will return the results eliminating Brazil from the search result.
3. Very useful. You can search for the specific details from the site.
   Ex: `HTML tutorial site=w3c.org` will return result from w3c.org site.
   There are couple of other keywords that you can use but these are important ones.

Comment: Thanks! But every time I learn about those tricks, Google keeps changing them and drives me mad :) I find filters so much easier and cleaner.

Comment: "`site=w3c.org`" should be `site:w3c.org`. Unfortunately you can't seem to search by _date_ by this method - which is the example given by the OP.

Comment: Wasn't it just an example, though (not precisely what the questioner wanted to know, per se)?